# Right programing language for developing application for Mac

Tags: macos, programming-languages, osx-leopard

I'm planing to buy a Mac. I would like to be able to develop GUI applications for Mac as well. Currently I develop in C# using VisualStudio as IDE. I also know Java and I'm familiar with NetBeans IDE. Application created in both of this languages can run on Mac (as can NetBeans IDE) but I was told that neither C# nor Java is recomended for MacOS X development.

So **what language is recomended for MacOS X development ?** I guess there is some  recommendation from Apple for the developers ? I would prefer Object-oriented easy-to-use programing language (nothing like C) with good IDE that supports GUI creating (GUI designer).

Thank you for answers

Comment: I think it would be Objective C

Comment: Objective C is sort of the default normal way for native apps, but you can do Java, Python, ruby, even Mono. If you use Objective C, it's got XCode as the IDE.

Comment: And the IDE would be Xcode, which includes a GUI designer called Interface Builder (well, to be precise, IB does more than GUI design).

Comment: For developing applications that run on several platforms including MacOS X, or for application that run almost exclusively on MacOS X (and perhaps iOS)?

Comment: I've heard rumors that IB is being integrated into XCode for the next version, which is sweet! :)

Comment: Question was ment as: "almost exclusively on MacOS X" but the other suggested way is also very interesting for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There really is only one choice and that's Objective-C and XCode, anything else and you'll be running into problems and/or limitations.

As some have mentioned Python is one suggestion but what GUI toolkit to use? Then packaging becomes a problem.

Mono is OK but still a little buggy (and slooooow) on Mac's.

I haven't tried Java but the Apple port of the Java VM has just beed deprecated, make of that what you will.

XCode is very very good and integrates nicely with Mac/iPhone/iPad etc. but Obj-C takes a while to learn coming from a C#/Java background, plus XCode forces you to use MVC patterns in everything which again can be a culture shock.

I would say go with Obj-C and XCode and learn something new.

Comment: Add: I haven't tried Java but the Apple port of the Java VM has just beed deprecated, make of that what you will. - I make of it that Oracle just don't like Apple :)

Comment: Or Apple don't like Oracle! ;o)

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C with Cocoa should be your first, second, and third choices. That being said the learning curve can be steep but half the fun of this business is learning something new.

At my job (Seapine Software) we extensively use C++ with the Qt framework on the Mac and it also seems to work fine. If I were starting out I'd definitely go with Objective-C.

Comment: Off topic: I use your TestTrack client for Mac daily :)

Comment: I have question abou Cocoa - what is it exactly ? Just a framework writen in Objective-C or what ? Can I use it with other languages then Objective-C ? If so, which languages ?

Comment: @drasto You're right, Cocoa is the main Mac framework. There are or used to be bridges from other languages to use it but Objective-C is far and away the most commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

It's Objective-C. But if you want a beautiful and easy language, you can use python with [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/). It'll look as native and, furthermore, it will make your applications multi-platform.

For the GUI designer, check [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/). It supports wxPython for exporting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an iOS developer & use Objective-C every day, but if I were writing an OS X app, I'd definitely try out [MacRuby](http://macruby.com/). However, there is little controversy that, at present, if you want to write OS X native apps, you eventually must learn Objective-C. Most, like myself, grow to like it. Moreover, on OS X you have the advantage that you can run it garbage-collected and possibly save yourself some bookkeeping.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Steinberg says it well in the introduction to his [*Cocoa Programming*](http://pragprog.com/titles/dscpq/cocoa-programming) book:

> Use Objective-C. Sure, you can write Cocoa applications in other languages. But for now, learn the native language. There is a lot of support for new developers on the various Apple lists and in the support documentation, tutorials, and sample code accessible from Xcode. You will have an easier time of getting your question answered if you use the lingua franca of Cocoa development.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's Objective C. But check this out.

If you are familiar with **HTML, CSS and Java Script, you can build platform independent desktop apps using Electron by Github**. It's indeed amazing.
The desktop Apps like **slack, atom, postman** are built using this framework.
Please refer: https://electron.atom.io/

You can also use **Qt which is a great cross-platform application development framework that is based on C++**.
Please refer: https://www.qt.io/developers/

Answer (score -1):

I started using swift to develop only Mac applications. But I wanted to use c for high performance apps, so I started using objective-c.