# Cocoa, XCode, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Right programing language for developing application for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634679/right-programing-language-for-developing-application-for-mac)

I'm a newbie to programming, i know HTML and CSS, but in terms of non web-development languages, im an idiot. I wanna program applications for mac, not for ipod touch or anything, and just downloaded Xcode, but all articles i've read are very unclear about what languages to learn. What languages do i need to know to do this?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634679/right-programing-language-for-developing-application-for-mac You should really search the site before asking a question to see if it has already been asked.

Comment: i apologize, i will do so next time. Thank you for letting me know! :)

Comment: No problem.  Just trying to get you on the right track here at SO. :-)

Comment: i am still confused, thank you for all the answers, but no one has told me whether i need to know cocoa! I know i need to know a little c and learn obj-c, but is cocoa required?

Comment: For the moment just think of Cocoa as being a part of obj-C.  Once you know more you'll understand better the distinction between the two.

Comment: because i did not know whether i needed to know it or not, i had heard something about it having to do with macs. Sorry if i offended you or anything...

Answer (score 2):

The language you need to learn is `Objective-C`.
`Cocoa` is the framework of libraries, `API`'s, and runtimes for `Mac OS X`.
`XCode` is the `IDE` you use to program in `Objective-C`.

Think of it this way: you can learn `Objective-C`, but without `Cocoa` you would have a very difficult time doing anything in the `OS X` environment without an `API`, which is where `Cocoa` comes in.

Comment: so i need to learn cocoa AND objective-c?

Comment: Cocoa is *framework* written in Objective-C.  If you only know HTML and CSS this distinction is probably unfamiliar.  If you have worked with any other web languages (e.g. PHP, Ruby, Python, JavaScript), the distinction is akin (very crudely) to the distinction between the aforementioned languages and, e.g., Codeigniter, Rails, Django, or jQuery, respectively.  Learning Objective-C is (relatively) fast and easy.  Cocoa, OTOH, is so big that probably no one knows everything in it.

Comment: From a web perspective you might say that programming in objective-c on a mac without Cocoa is like trying to web programming without the DOM.

Comment: You need to learn Objective-C in order to use Cocoa. Cocoa gives you methods (functions) to do things in OS X. For example, if you wanted to create a window for your application in OS X, you'd write the code in Objective-C, but you'd be using methods (functions) from Cocoa to interact with OS X.

Comment: OK.  Cocoa (again crudely) is to Objective-C as Django or Turbo Gears is to Python.  Except Cocoa is also written by Apple.  (Taking this tortured analogy further, one might say that the Python Standard Library is to Python as Foundation is to Objective-C.  This is imperfect since Foundation is part of Cocoa, but hopefully you get the general idea.)

Answer (score 1):

The main language on `OS X` is `Objective-C`.
This is an extension to the standard `C` language, so knowing at least the basics of `C` would be a good starting point here.

`Cocoa` is the main application framework applications on `OS X` are using.
Get yourself a book to learn that!

I recommend the book from `Aaron Hillegass`.
It's amazing!

Comment: so i need the basics of C, and also learn obj-c and cocoa?

Comment: Cocoa basically provides classes and functions you can use to develop Mac applications. It wouldn't be bad to know C, but you can also learn Obj-C as a first programming language. Many Obj-C or cocoa books have a short introductory section with C.

Comment: I concur on the Hillegass book.  And a new edition just came out too!

Comment: As an aside, Cocoa is built on top of a bunch of pure C APIs (such as Core Foundation, Core Graphics, Core Text, Core Audio, etc.) that you will probably eventually need to use when you start doing more advanced things.  But to start with, I agree, you can get away with little to no pure C.